# Populate V-select from json

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm having a problem populating my v-select from JSON that I receive from the backend. I'm new with vuetify and some of the solution shared online is quite confusing for me.

This is my JSON

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "quantityOnHand": 7,
        "idealQuantity": 10,
        "product": {
            "id": 2,
            "createOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "updateOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "name": "10LB Dark Roast",
            "description": "10LB of Dark Roast Coffee Beans",
            "price": 67.0,
            "isTaxable": true,
            "isArchived": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "quantityOnHand": 48,
        "idealQuantity": 10,
        "product": {
            "id": 1,
            "createOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "updateOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "name": "10LB Light Roast",
            "description": "10LB of Light Roast Coffee Beans",
            "price": 67.0,
            "isTaxable": true,
            "isArchived": false
        }
    },
```

This is my Vuejs front-end code:

```
                    <template v-slot:[`item`]="{ inventory }">
                      <v-select
                        :items="inventory.product.name"
                        label="Product Receive"
                      ></v-select>
                    </template>
```

And this is the script I'm using(Typescript), that might be related to it.

```
  inventory: IProductInventory[] = [];

  async intialize() {
    this.inventory = await inventoryService.getInventory();
    await this.$store.dispatch("assignSnapshots");
  }
  async created() {
    await this.intialize();
  }
```

This is the interface for IProductInventory and IProduct

```
export interface IProduct {
  id: number;
  createdOn: Date;
  updatedOn: Date;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  isTaxable: boolean;
  isArchived: boolean;
}

export interface IProductInventory {
  id: number;
  product: IProduct;
  quantityOnHand: number;
  idealQuantity: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your array via `items` prop:

```html
<v-select
  label="Product Receive"
  :items="inventoryItems">
</v-select>
```

and for `inventoryItems` you can use computed property:

```js
computed: {
  inventoryItems () {
    return yourArray?.map(inventory => ({
      text: inventory.product.name,
      value: inventory.product.id
    }))
  }
}
```

See [v-select API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/) for more details.

Comment: Is it a typo or is there a use to the question mark after `yourArray` variable ?

Comment: It's called optional chaining https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining. I use it to avoid error if yourArray is `undefined` at very first.

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought it was for but couldn't find any docs !

Comment: It's giving me an error. Property 'product' does not exist on type 'never'.

Comment: @MuhdDanie Sorry I didn't use TypeScript. I guess you may need to declare type something like `yourArray?.map(inventory => <IProduct>{...})`.